# Multiple Popups With One Click like kayak Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, click

I has to develop for a client a function to open multiple popups of information in just one click.

I create a function like this:

```
<script>
var index = 0 ;
function openWindows()
{
    var url = new Array() ;
    url[0] = "http://www.marca.com" ;
    url[1] = "http://www.google.es" ;
    for(i=0; i < url.length ; i++)
    {
        window.open(url[index],"ident_"+index) ;
        index = index + 1 ;
    }
    index = 0 ;
}
</script>
```

I call this function with the next code

```
<a href="javascript:openWindows()">Open Popups</a>
```

This function runs perfectly on Firefox, but on Chrome and Internet Explorer i get the second popup blocked ( the first one opens perfectly )

I dont know how to do it.At first, i thought that it was not possible, but then, i see a website ( http://www.kayak.es/ ) where you choose how many sites do u want to compare with kayak and he opens all the selected sites in Popups with one click.

Someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.I have IE 9,and chrome :Version 22.0.1207.1

Comment: Do u get both popups ?

Comment: Yes i have got both popups.

Comment: omg !! :( i cant get it running. I have installed by default chrome and IE. Do u change ur security settings?

Comment: No i didn't modify security settings.All settings are default.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. Try to check your security settings in Chrome and IE, they are blocking multiple popups in some way.

Comment: Popups are working fine in Kayak.es without change anything in my security settings, but my code doesnt :\

Answer (score 0):

Try passing to the second popup a parameter to tell him to open the next popup and so on.
Maybe the browser check to opener window to block multiple popups.
Or try to put some microtime-sleep between each opening.